# URL rewrite with internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have already checked a few threads/questions here to try and fix the URL rewrite issue on my site.

For some reason it's not working as expected.

Please find my `.htaccess` file content here:

```
Options -indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^notfound$ notfound.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule medical/license/(.*)/ medical.php?license=$1 [END]
```

I'm currently on a shared hosting, and hence am not able to get access to any log files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule medical/license/(.*)/ medical.php?license=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^notfound$ notfound.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, looks like i have to do a complete rewrite as its conflicting with other pages. this was done by another coder and he has done it in a wrong way i think

Comment: So you are still getting 500 using my suggested code?

Comment: its all messed up.. the urls are getting clashed with other urls :(

Comment: Well question about resolving 500 error so I think that's what this answer does. For other problems you will have provide all the details in a new question.